# Pyinstaller Activex Attribute Error with wxPython

Tags: python, module, wxpython, pyinstaller, attributeerror

For some reason, when I compile my app with Pyinstaller, it gives me an error when run:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'activex'
```

And the top of my code (the code itself is extremely long). I've also removed a whole load of arrays at the top, which contain text for the app.

```
from wxPython.wx import *
from wx import *
from wx.lib.wordwrap import wordwrap
import sys, os, re

class CheatulousFrame(wxFrame):

    APP_STORAGE = ""
    APP_REGISTERED = False
    APP_WORKING = False

    ## ARRAYS GO HERE

    def __init__(self, parent, ID, title):
        wxFrame.__init__(self, parent, ID, title, (-1, -1), wxSize(600, 300))
        self.Centre()

        self.Bind(EVT_CLOSE, self.quitApp)

        self.getDataPath()
        self.checkRegistered()

        self.menuBar = wxMenuBar()
        self.createMenu(self.file_menu, "File")
        self.createMenu(self.conn_menu, "Connection")
        if self.APP_REGISTERED:
            self.createMenu(self.regt_menu, "Registration")
        else:
            self.createMenu(self.regf_menu, "Registration")
        self.createMenu(self.devt_menu, "Dev Tools")
        self.SetMenuBar(self.menuBar)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using the activex stuff from wxPython? By the way, you shouldn't import wx like this:

```
from wxPython.wx import *
from wx import *
```

The recommended way is

```
import wx
```

And then prepend everything with "wx". wxPython is HUGE and by doing it your way, you import almost everything from it, which you don't need. The "wxPython.wx" is super old, I don't know why that's even included any more. Definitely don't use that.